# Is wireless Android Auto possible on a Toyota RAV4 Hybrid?

Tags: toyota, infotainment

I am trying to connect Android Auto (Samsung 9+, Android 10) **wirelessly** to my Toyota RAV4 Hybrid (2021). Is this possible?

I have no problems with the **wired** USB connection, but Android Auto is not detected without that cable (I added a Wi-Fi hotspot just in case). An [article](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-auto/#wireless) suggests that a wireless connection may be possible:

> Phones compatible with Wireless Android Auto
>
> (...)
>
> A Google Pixel or a Samsung Galaxy phone running on Android 10. ← my case

Answer (score 1):

The car and phone must both be Android Auto wireless compatible. The cars owners manual should indicate if it's available on your Toyota. Also the dealership may have a tech person to help you out.